# What happens in the stack when a const reference is bound to a temporary?

Tags: c++, stack, const-reference

The C++ standard allows to bind const references to rvalues, therefore extending the lifetime of the temporary until the reference goes out of scope. However, I cannot figure out how this is actually compiled, let me explain with an example:

```
std::string foo() {
    return std::string("foo");
}

void bar() {
    VeryBigObject obj;
    // Perhaps do something with the big object
}

int main(int, char **) {
    const std::string &foo_str = foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, using an x86 architecture as an example, what happens there is that first the function `foo()` is called and the string object is constructed in the stack, which means that the needed amount of space is subtracted from the `rsp` register (assuming 64 bit architecture); afterwards, the `rsp` register is returned to its original value, freeing the stack space that the function `foo()` was filling, and, if I understand correctly, the call to `bar()` would use that stack space to construct the `VeryBigObject`, which would overwrite the string.

With all this in mind, how can the lifetime of the string be prolonged after the call to `foo()` in the assembly domain?

Comment: My (informal) understanding of references is that C++ compilers transform them to pointers.

Comment: It would be a very shoddy compiler if it behaves the way you describe it.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Sometimes they're implemented like pointers; sometimes (like here) the referenced object is known to the compiler, so it can generate code to access it directly with no run-time indirection.

Answer (score 7):

The temporary return value will be constructed in the stack frame of `main`, either by copying/moving a temporary from that of `foo` or, more likely, using RVO to elide the copy and construct it directly in the caller's frame.

Once bound to a reference, the temporary will live as long as the reference. Effectively, the temporary is managed in exactly the same way that a named variable with the same scope would be.

Comment: That is how I understand it needs to be done. My doubt here is with the standard, which specifies that RVO is optional, but however it guarantees that the  reference effectively behaves as a reference, which means that **the referenced object won't be copied**. This essentially forces the compiler to use RVO, even though a stubborn compiler implementer decided not to, right?

Comment: @gdasamu: Without RVO, one temporary is created in the frame of `foo`, then copied/moved to create a second in the frame of `main` to form the function call result. With RVO, just one is created directly in `main`. In either case, the reference binds to the one in `main`.